# How to write Beautifulsoup4 result to csv?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from multiple links using bs4. I manage to get the ideal result when printing it to the console but I am not sure how can I write it to CSV while maintaining the data strucutre I want.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

urls =[
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/solutions4savings",
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/astute-capital",
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/think-finance-solution",
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/fixed-rate-finder",
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/art-escrow-art-escrow-clone-uk-registered-company",
"https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/protectedrates2021com",
]

for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    page_html = req.content
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
    name = page_soup.select_one('body > div.dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas > div.main-container.js-quickedit-main-content > section > div.region.region-content > div:nth-child(2) > div > article > div > section.copy-block.component > div > h3')
    details = page_soup.findAll("strong")

    print (name.text)
    for detail in details:
        print(detail.text, detail.next_sibling)
```

The example of printed output:

```
Unauthorised firm - Solutions4Savings
Address:  85 Great Portland Street, London, W1W 7LT
Website:  https://solutions4savings.co.uk

Unauthorised firm - Fixed Rate Finder
Address:  12 Constance Street, London, E16 2DQ
Telephone:  02037699243
Website:  www.fixedratefinder.co.uk
```

Anyone knows how can I write it to CSV?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it to csv using the "with" keyword
in the example the open function takes a few parameters,
`fileName.csv` is the file name that you want to create `w` is the write operation and `newline=''` will create a new line after each write.
`records` is a list of lists that contains all the data that you extracted in the correct order

```py
import csv

with open("fileName.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Address', 'Telephone', 'Website'])
    writer.writerows(records)
```

You can read more about the with keyword [here](https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)